# How do I extract a sequence of contiguous prespecified words from a list?

Tags: python, string, nlp

I have two lists given:

> `list_1` is a list of words which I'm interested in
> `list_2` is a tokenized sequence of words extracted from text

What I want to do is to extract sequences of words out of `list_2` if they are contained in `list_1` and concatenate them as long as the following word in `list_2` is also contained in `list_1`.

Unfortunately I don't quite know how to start. Any tipp would be much appreciated.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to try:

```
text = ("What I want to do is to extract sequences of words out of list_2 " 
        "if they are contained in list_1 and concatenate them as long as the "
        "following word in list_2 is also contained in list_1. Is to")

list1 = ["is", "to", "do"]
list2 = text.lower().split(" ")

def extract(list2, list1):
    res = []
    string = ""
    for word in list2:
        if word in list1:
            string += " " + word
        elif string:
            res.append(string.strip())
            string = ""
    res.append(string.strip())
    return res

extract(list2, list1)
```

---

```
['to do is to', 'is', 'is to']
```

Comment: @Jonas Did it answer your question? Was it helpful? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers